# Data encoding is wrong when jdk is run through a bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, java-8

Hi I have a java service which gets data from an api and it insert that data into a mysql db table. The issue is, when I run the script, some characters are stored with wrong format. (eg:- mgÃ¥en)

But if I run the same java service using my IDE, this doesn't occur. And I can't think why this happens.

Can anyone suggest any reason why this would occur?
Thanks!

Update::
My script is like this =>

`java -jar SERVICE.jar $3 $then`

Comment: Do not use the system’s default encoding. Always specify an encoding when converting between bytes and characters.

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it? Do I have to specify it in the script?
 @Holger

Comment: I can’t tell you how to change the code without knowing the code. There are tons of methods in the Java API overloaded to allow either, explicitly specifying an encoding or implicitly using the system’s default. For all operations relevant to the database rather than user input, you have to use the alternative with an explicit encoding. E.g., instead of `new FileReader(fileName)` use `new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileName), encoding)`, instead of `new String(bytearray)` use `new String(bytearray, encoding)` and so on…

Comment: Thing is when I run the code using IDE the encoding that get saved is correct. but when I run the script to run the jar file, then the issue occurs. So can it be an issue with my script? I use this in a windows machine.

Comment: It implies that your IDE runs the application with a different default encoding setting, e.g. Netbeans defaults to always run applications with `UTF-8` instead of the actual system’s encoding. You *can* set the encoding with `-Dfile.encoding=…` on the command line, but this requires awareness about which encoding is the right one for your database and when you are at it, you should fix your application to always use that correct encoding in the first place, instead of requiring the surrounding environment to have the encoding as default.

Comment: @Holger Thank you! I think I understood the problem now. I am using a BufferedReader to read the data, 
  BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream(), "UTF-8"));
adding the "UTF-8" did the trick!

Comment: Mind that for certain URL protocols, like `http`, a declaration of the correct encoding is sent in the meta data, so you can use `url.openConnection().getContentEncoding()` to get it. For protocols like `file`, this will likely return the system’s default encoding though…

Comment: The URL protocol in the api I am using is https, maybe that's why I get an error, when I try to use url.openConnection().getContentEncoding(). Thank you for your help! much appreciated.

Comment: @Holger, hi, when you meant the system's encoding, what do you mean? the JRE's encoding? or the OS's encoding? This problem has bugged me for a long time!

Comment: The JRE’s default encoding, which is usually initialized to an operating specific encoding, e.g. `windows-1252` on western Windows versions, but can be overridden, e.g. using the `-Dfile.encoding=…` option on the command line.